# The power operator in Java?

Tags: java, vb.net, math, int

When I run the following Visual Basic code :

```
Dim b As Double
b = (2 ^ 16 - 1) * Math.Sqrt(Math.Sqrt((a / (2 ^ 8 - 1))))
```

(Assuming `a` is a double whose value is 15.0)
The result I get for `b` is about 32,275.

But when I run the following Java code, which is supposed to do the same as above:

```
double b;
b = (2 ^ 16 - 1) * Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt((a / (2 ^ 8 - 1))));
```

Again with `a` being 15, I get a much different result: about 17.

Both are solving this equation:

[image]

Why is this so? For what I'm working on, the Visual Basic yields result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`^` is [XOR operator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in java. Use `Math.pow(2,8)` which is `2 ^ 8` in Visual Basic.

Comment: Besides the XOR thing, in Java a is int or double? Because if its int, then a / x is int too.

Comment: `a` is a double value in this case.

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked. I was wondering why `Math.pow()` even existed if I could just use `^` (which I now know I can't).

Comment: Nice succinct answer (1+), Eng. Congratulations on the high number of up-votes!