# why does 2^0 return 2 in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the ^ operator do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)
>   [The power ^ in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101515/the-power-in-java)

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but i didn´t found anything in SO.

So can someone explaint me why

```
     System.out.println((2^0));
```

this does return `2`?

i was expecting a `1`.

Comment: ^ is xor, not the power operator

Comment: Suggested search in the future: `x operators`. Replace `x` with the language in question: it will cover most questions of "Why/What does a <op> b ..?".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `^` operator does not mean "raise 2 to the 0th power".  It's a bitwise exclusive OR operator.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

In order to do that, your code should look like this:

```
double one = Math.pow(2.0, 0.0);  // Silly, but you can do it.
```

Don't be surprised if the answer comes out to something that's not exactly 1.0.  You'll need to know about [how floating point numbers work](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: y thx, i just forgot that ^ is not the real pow operator ...

Answer (score 6):

The `^` sign means [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR) and not pow. Try `Math.Pow(2.0, 0.0)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

^ in Java is Bitwise exclusive-OR.
so 2(1 0) ^(XOR) 0(0 0) =1 0 ie 2 !!!
Got it?